# Cleaning a GTM Template

Tags: google-tag-manager

We are currently using a GTM template provided by an advertising firm. We intend to no longer use this firm but would like to keep the same tags in place. We don't want our data being sent back to them as a result of the GTM template. I have taken out any sensitive information but would like to know which values to remove or change.

The Template URL under Add to Cart would obviously need to be changed but what about container id or path? Are these just informational concerning the account that exported this file or does this pass data back to their account? The specified tagManagerUrl does not match my account.

Anything else to look out for? I have attached a small segment of the file.

Thank you

```
{
    "exportFormatVersion": 2,
    "exportTime": "2019-01-10 11:11:11",
    "containerVersion": {
        "path": "accounts/XXX/containers/XXX/versions/0",
        "accountId": "XXX",
        "containerId": "XXX",
        "containerVersionId": "0",
        "container": {
            "path": "accounts/XXX/containers/XXX",
            "accountId": "XXX",
            "containerId": "XXX",
            "name": "the Container",
            "publicId": "GTM-XXX",
            "usageContext": [
                "WEB"
            ],
            "fingerprint": "XXX",
            "tagManagerUrl": "https://tagmanager.google.com/#/container/accounts/XXX/containers/XXX/workspaces?apiLink=container"
        },
        "tag": [
            {
                "accountId": "XXX",
                "containerId": "XXX",
                "tagId": "10",
                "name": "Add Item to Cart",
                "type": "img",
                "parameter": [
                    {
                        "type": "BOOLEAN",
                        "key": "useCacheBuster",
                        "value": "true"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TEMPLATE",
                        "key": "url",
                        "value": "https://AdVendorURL/xxx/item?&XXX"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TEMPLATE",
                        "key": "cacheBusterQueryParam",
                        "value": "gtmcb"
                    }
                ],
                "fingerprint": "XXX",
                "firingTriggerId": [
                    "7"
                ],
                "tagFiringOption": "ONCE_PER_EVENT",
                "monitoringMetadata": {
                    "type": "MAP"
                }
            },
```

Comment: Do you have admin rights in the Google Tag Manager account and container?

Comment: I have admin rights on the account where the template was installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would not remove anything from the template. In your Google Tag Manager container go to Admin > Import Container and follow the instructions to import the configuration. Once you have complete go to your Workspace and select Tags from the menu. Locate the tag Add Item to Cart and remove it.